# ufw configuration nat ppp0

Tags: firewall, ufw, pppoe, nat

please some tips how i can allow this request in ufw:

```
[UFW BLOCK] IN=ppp0 OUT=eth0 MAC= SRC=10.11.22.2 DST=8.8.4.4 LEN=71 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=127 ID=52 PROTO=UDP SPT=59405 DPT=53 LEN=51
```

i tried this but not helps:

```
To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Anywhere                   ALLOW       10.11.22.2
```

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, solution is to allow default forwarding policy.

file:

```
/etc/default/ufw
```

line:

```
DEFAULT_FORWARD_POLICY="ACCEPT"
```